# How to merge two columns in open office calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have two column in open office calc.
I want to  merge then like following

```
name    last name  fullname 
john    carter      


name    last name   fullname    
john    carter      john carter
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I did this like following way
In the column where you want to get the merged values write following.

```
=A2 & " " & B2
```

and drag to the end of column.

**Update:** added screenshot

Click on the cell, then hold from the right corner and drag.
[image]

Comment: but thats just for fields A2 and B2.. not all of column A and column B

Comment: @Martin Drag to the end of column.

Comment: How to drag that? Tried dragging. no results

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 8):

This is just another option,

just click the function wizard and select 'concatenat', in that enter which column you want to enter as text1 as and second column in text2 then when you click ok you will get an concatenated column like below image

[image]

so in the c th column you will get as a1.jpg.

Comment: If you need additional formatting characters, enclose them in double quotes and separate them by semi-colon. Ex: =CONCATENATE("[";D4;",";E4;"]")  gets me [123,456] where 123 and 456 are from cells D4 and E4 respectively.